# Meaning of を以って

Tags: grammar

> 今回の原稿**を以って**きっと、私以外にも真実に至る者が必ず現れる。

What does this part mean? I guess it would be "by means of" or something like this, but just in case I'd like confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as meaning is concerned:

> 「～～を以{も}って」＝「～～で」

It means:

> "with ~~", "by means of ~~", etc.

So, the sentence would roughly mean:

> "With the (new) manuscript this time, others besides me will certainly reach the Truth as well."

Comment: Is it in a specific register? For instance, more formal than で or something like this or is it the same?

Comment: Yes, it is more formal than で.   You don't really use 以って or 以ちまして in informal daily speech.

Comment: i thought it was written 「以て」?

Comment: @istrasci I believe both are used, but 以て is more common because the derived word is considered not to inflect, which makes the okurigana unnecessary.  (But then, where would 以ちまして fit in?)  Some sources recommend writing the word in kana instead, for what it's worth.